# WebUtility.HtmlDecode fails to decode a String

Tags: c#, json

I am using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` to attempt to decode a string, a portion of which is below:

```
checkin=%7B%22id%22%3A%224f612730e4b071dd72e3749d%22%2C%22createdAt%22%3A1331767088%2C%22type%22%3A%22checkin%22%2C%22timeZone%22%3A%22America%5C%2FDenver%22%2C
```

But, `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` fails to decode it, any of it. In case it matters, here is how I am generating the string:

```
public static Dictionary<String, dynamic> DeserializeRequestStream(Stream requestStream, int contentLength)
        {
            requestStream.Position = 0; //Since a custom route with post data AND an ID passed in a parameter reads this stream. Damn bugs.
            var bytes = new byte[contentLength];
            requestStream.Read(bytes, 0, contentLength);    //(int)requestStream.Length - contentLength
            var jsonResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            var decodedResponse =  WebUtility.HtmlEncode(jsonResponse);
           //...snip...
        }
```

This is supposedly encoded JSON data, that I am reading from a POST request. How would I decode this string to regular JSON?

**Edit:** Lasse V. Karlsen points out that this is actually URL encoded, and that I have been barking up the wrong tree. The question still remains: how would I decode this?

Comment: `%7B` is *URL* encoded, not *HTML* encoded. HTML encoding deals with ampersands and the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to change `HtmlDecode` to `UrlDecode`.

Reason: The input string `checkin=%7B%22id%22%3A...` is URL encoded, not HTML encoded.

Comment: Thanks! I had found that method on Google as well. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx